# multiple site-wide cookies / $config['cookie_domain']

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

Under the site-enabled **www.test.com**, I have multiple VirtualHost configurations. ServerName varies (eg. *test1.com*, *test2.com*, *test3.com*) but points only into one DocumentRoot.

I can detect which server name the user is currently in by using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. However we have a particular page which requires pointing to a specific subdomain. Enabling site-wide cookies is definitely a go for this project.

My concern thus: Is there anyway to have multiple `$config['cookie_domain']` in **config.php**? So I can have this matching idea:

```
$server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if($server_name == "test1.com")
    $config['cookie_domain'] = ".test1.com";
else if($server_name == "test2.com")
    $config['cookie_domain'] = ".test2.com";
... // so on
```

I even tried adding this into **config.php** but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing should work for each individual domain, but the nature of cookies is that they are inherently not cross-domain.  You'll need some additional magic to make cookies (or session data) accessible across multiple top-level domains.